# Cant set AngularJS variable in ng-reapeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to implement list which should be fully visible only after the click.
But when I try to set value on `ng-click`, value scope is only in on clicked element.

```
<ul data-ng-init="showIataList = false">
  {{showIataList}} <-- always false :( but should be true after click on link from list
  <li data-ng-repeat="value in data.departureIataList">
    <a href="javascript:"
       data-ng-if="$index < 3 || showIataList">
       {{value}}
    </a>
    {{showIataList}}
    <a href="javascript:"
       data-ng-if="!showIataList && $index == 3"
       data-ng-click="showIataList = true">
        {{showIataList}} <-- after click is true, but true should be and on the top showIataList variable
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

FYI,  every `ng-repeat` item has his own scope. This is a reason why `data-ng-click="showIataList = true"` works for specific scope and not main `$scope`.

You can write for example:

```
$scope.data.showIataList = false;
```

and everything will work

---

or in your case: `<ul data-ng-init="data.showIataList = false">`

<kbd>[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jv0ybac0/)</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

The problem is because of this tag. It has ng-if inside so it create a new scope and inherit data from parent scope.

```
<a href="javascript:"
   data-ng-if="!showIataList && $index == 3"
   data-ng-click="showIataList = true">
```

Because `ngIf` inherit from parent so your `showIataList` is also copied to `ngIf`.

```
parentScope.showIataList = ngIf.showIataList
```

But after you click on link, `ngIf.showIataList` is changed but that change will not propagate to `parentScope.showIataList` (because `showIataList` is (primitive value)

That why you see inside `ngIf`, `showIataList` is true but in `parentScope` it remain false.

You can fix it by move showIataList into an object like this.

```
<ul data-ng-init="iataList = {isShow:false}">
  {{iataList.isShow}} 
  <li data-ng-repeat="value in data.departureIataList">
    <a href="javascript:"
       data-ng-if="$index < 3 || iataList.isShow">
       {{value}}
    </a>
    {{showIataList}}
    <a href="javascript:"
       data-ng-if="!iataList.isShow&& $index == 3"
       data-ng-click="iataList.isShow= true">
        {{iataList.isShow}} 
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```